# Extreme confusion with the instanton solutions and the measure on $\mathbb{R}^4$ or $S^4$..

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mathematical-physics

I am experiencing some serious confusion with instantons..

In Nakahara's "Geometry, Topology and Physics" p.65, or Weinberg "Quantum Theory of Fields Vol 2 p.450~452, they say that on $\mathbb{R}^4$, with $r:=\lvert x \rvert$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$, the instanton solution is given by

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}_\mu=\frac{r^2}{\lambda^2+r^2}U(x)^{-1} \partial_\mu U(x)
\end{equation}

for $U(x):=\frac{1}{r}(x_4-ix_j \sigma_j)$, where $\sigma_j$'s are Pauli matrices and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary positive number that represents the size of the instanton.

Then, the Nakahara book says the corresponding field strength tensor is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu}:=\frac{4\lambda^4}{\lambda^2+r^2} \sigma_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
with $\sigma_{i j}:=\frac{1}{4i}[\sigma_i, \sigma_j]$ and $\sigma_{i0}=-\sigma_{0i}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_i$.

However, the serious problem is that the integral
\begin{equation}
\int d^4x \text{ tr} [\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{F}^{\mu \nu}]
\end{equation}
on $\mathbb{R}^4$ does NOT converge with the above $\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu}$..... In later chapters, the Nakahara book suddenly changes the domain of integral to $S^4$ and proceeds the calculation and gets the well-known result of the Index Theorem.

But, in p.65 of "Geometry, Topology and Physics" or in p.450~452 of Weinberg's "Quantum Theory of Fields", it seems so obvious that they are denoting the domain of integration as $\mathbb{R}^4$; for example, eqn (23.5.2) of Weinberg has $r \to \infty$ and eqn (23.5.10) of Weinberg uses the notation $(d^4x)_E$, which means the integration on Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^4$....Nakahara (1.301a) also uses the notation $r \to \infty$, which clearly implies $\mathbb{R}^4$.

What am I missing? It is extremely confusing and frustrating...Could anyone please clarify??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for $F_{\mu\nu}$ is not correct:
$$
F_{\mu\nu} = \frac{4\lambda^2\sigma_{\mu\nu}}{(r^2 +\lambda^2)^2}
$$
and the integral is
$$
\int tr {F^2} \propto \int \frac{r^3 dr}{(r^2+\lambda^2)^4}
$$
which is convergent.

Comment: @artic tern, Weird I have deleted copy.

Comment: @Keith Look at https://laces.web.cern.ch/LACES14/notes/Inst14.pdf for the gauge field and integral.

Comment: Oh......Nakahara and Weinberg are both somewhat incorrect in the details......Thank you....

Comment: @Keith . Nakahara's interesting but difficult to read book is still on my list. I appreciate your question. What exactly is the detail he is incrorrect about ? Need to learn.